# Recorded Macro in Excel fails on run

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
Sub Macro3()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://..." _
        , Destination:=Range("Sheet6!$G$23"))

        ''// The line above fails with the error:
        ''// "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
        ''//     The destination range is not on the same worksheet
        ''//     that the Query table is being created on."

        .Name = _
        "?tmp=toolbar_FlvTube_homepage&prt=..."
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

The recorded macro fails as described in the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You recorded the macro while Sheet 6 was active, but are now trying to run it on a different sheet. To run the macro for the *current* active sheet, simply change the code as follows:

```
Sub Macro3()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://..." _
        , Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("$G$23"))
        ...
    End With
End Sub
```

***Edit:*** (in response to comment):

> I need to be able to paste the results of the query to a different sheet then the active one since the macro can be run at any time and must be paste to the same location everytime. Perhaps there is a way to change your active sheet with code?

The error happens when the two sheets are different, so if you want the magic to happen on a particular sheet, you should specify that sheet instead of using `ActiveSheet`. The following code would always place the QueryTable on Sheet6:

```
Sub Macro3()
    With Sheet6.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://..." _
        , Destination:=Sheet6.Range("$G$23"))
        ...
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to be able to paste the results of the query to a different sheet then the active one since the macro can be run at any time and must be paste to the same location everytime. Perhaps there is a way to change your active sheet with code?

Comment: Absolutely! Just add `Sheet6.Activate` to your code, right before the `With ...` block.

Comment: Or, better yet, change Both `ActiveSheet` references to `Sheet6`.